# Eclipse: Create a group of tabs(Console, Servers, Problems … )

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to create a hotkey to **hide** and **show** the entire bottom tab group? The one that **normally contains** Console, Problems, Servers and so on...

I want to have it a **fastview** but as far as I know this is only **possible per tab** within that group.

I want the **entire group** to **appear** on a **hotkey** and as a fast view.

I am hoping for a miracle here. Perhaps there is a plugin for this? Eclipse 3.4

Thanks!

Comment: You can adjust the horizontal top bar of the bottom tab group.  Make the bottom tab group small when you want more editor space.  Make the bottom tab group larger when you need to see the Problems view or the Console view.

Comment: Yep, that is one way but not optimal. Not hotkey either... perhaps the best one out there though... thanks

Comment: Would minimising the tab view (with a mouse click on the minimise button), and then maximising each view in that group (as a fast view) using a hot key help?

Comment: @katsharp Possibly, what are you recommending I do for that?

Comment: The body of the question doesn't match the question. You asked how to create a group of tabs, now you seem to want to know how to hide or show them.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to maximize editor space, you can double-click on an editor tab and it will grow to fill the entire window. Double-click again and it will restore back down, showing all the other view tab groups.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an ok solution:

Minimise the tag group (minimise button on top left).

Whenever you want to access a view from that group use Cntrl+F7 - this brings up a view menu.

Hold down cntrl and keep hitting f7 to go to the view you want to display, let go. If the view was hidden it is now shown as a fast view.